# How to return users posts within the same layout in template? Django

Tags: django

On the summary page I'm displaying all of the users favourite posts: aircraft and airline.

I've got the fav posts working for the aircraft, but since the aircraft model is so similar to the airline one, I don't want to create a second section for the airline posts. I want to posts to be merged in the same section.

The airline model only has different fields like: fleet size, no. of destinatons, alliance. They way I've styled both of them is the same. How do I merge them? I know you use an if statement but Im confused on how to do it?

**View**

```
def account_overview(request):
    fav_aircraft = FavoritedAircraft.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
    fav_airline = FavoritedAirline.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
    return render(request, 'account/account_overview.html', {'favAircraft':fav_aircraft,'favAirline':fav_airline})
```

**Template**

```
{% if favorite %}
    {% for favorite in favAircraft %}
    <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-sm-3 item">
      <div class="box"><img src="{{ favorite.aircraft.image.url }}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="{{ favorite.aircraft.title }}"/></a>
          <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ favorite.get_absolute_url }}">{{ favorite.aircraft.name }}</a></h3>
          <h4>Manufacturer: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.manufacturer }}</i></h4>
          <h4>Range: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.maximum_range }} NM</i></h4>
          <h4> Passengers: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.passengers }}</i></h4>
          <h4> Speed: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.cruising_speed }} KT</i></h4>
          <button class=" favorite btn btn-default {% if aircraft.id in favorited_aircraft_ids %}added{% endif %}" data-aircraft-id="{{ aircraft.id }}"><span class="add">Add</span><span class="remove">Remove</span> Favorite</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {%endfor%}
{% else %}
  <h2 class="text-center">Opps.. You don't seem to have any favourited posts..</h2></div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

from itertools import chain

final_list = list(chain(fav_aircraft, fav_airline))

Comment: Can you go into more detail? How would I use that within the view and template?

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions here:

1. You can either create a single list in the view containing both aircraft and airline objects and give it a generic name like objects to display them in the template
2. Create another snippet html template and include it twice in your original template, once with the airline objects nd once with the aircraft objects

Answer (score 0):

Just have both the loops in the same div your template

```
{% if favorite %}
    <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-sm-3 item">
        {% for favorite in favAircraft %}
          <div class="box"><img src="{{ favorite.aircraft.image.url }}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="{{ favorite.aircraft.title }}"/></a>
          <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ favorite.get_absolute_url }}">{{ favorite.aircraft.name }}</a></h3>
          <h4>Manufacturer: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.manufacturer }}</i></h4>
          <h4>Range: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.maximum_range }} NM</i></h4>
          <h4> Passengers: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.passengers }}</i></h4>
          <h4> Speed: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.cruising_speed }} KT</i></h4>
          <button class=" favorite btn btn-default {% if aircraft.id in favorited_aircraft_ids %}added{% endif %}" data-aircraft-id="{{ aircraft.id }}"><span class="add">Add</span><span class="remove">Remove</span> Favorite</button>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}

        {% for favorite in favAirline %}
          <div class="box"><img src="{{ favorite.airline.image.url }}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="{{ favorite.airline.title }}"/></a>
          <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ favorite.get_absolute_url }}">{{ favorite.airline.name }}</a></h3>
          <h4>Alliance: <i>{{ favorite.airline. alliance }}</i></h4>
          <h4>Fleet Size: <i>{{ favorite.airline.fleet_size }} NM</i></h4>
          <h4> No. of Destinations: <i>{{ favorite.airline.no_of_destinations }}</i></h4>
          <button class=" favorite btn btn-default {% if airline.id in favorited_airline_ids %}added{% endif %}" data-airline-id="{{ airline.id }}"><span class="add">Add</span><span class="remove">Remove</span> Favorite</button>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
{% else %}
  <h2 class="text-center">Opps.. You don't seem to have any favourited posts..</h2></div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining two querysets of different models can be either ver simple or pretty complicated, depending on what you want to do with the result.

But first let's take a look at your current view and template, specifically your if statement:

```
{% if favorite %}
```

yet there is no variable named `favorite` in your context dictionary:

```
return render(request, 'account/account_overview.html', {'favAircraft':fav_aircraft,'favAirline':fav_airline})
```

so to fix that, i'd add this to your view:

```
favorite = fav_aircraft.exists() or fav_airline.exists()
```

and this to your render call:

```
return render(request, 'account/account_overview.html', {'favAircraft':fav_aircraft,'favAirline':fav_airline, 'favorite':favorite})
```

With this done, your if statement should work properly in the template.
Now to the more complicated issue, iterating over both aircrafts and airlines.

Now one way (not really recommended) to do this is to just use two loops in your template but as i just said, this isn't recommended, it clutters the template unnecesarily if only common attributes are being used.

Instead we'll keep all model related logic in the view, so what we need is a single list that contains the content of both querysets:

```
favorites = list(fav_aircraft) + list(fav_airline)
```

After doing this you no longer need your favorite variable, because we can just check for favorites in the template, we also don't need the two separate querysets anymore after doing this, so the render statement becomes quiet simple:

```
return render(request, 'account/account_overview.html', {'favorites':favorites})
```

final view code would be:

```
def account_overview(request):
  fav_aircraft = FavoritedAircraft.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
  fav_airline = FavoritedAirline.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
  favorites = list(fav_aircraft) + list(fav_airline)
  return render(request, 'account/account_overview.html', {'favorites':favorites})
```

Now your template should look something like this:

```
{% if favorites %}
    {% for favorite in favorites %}
    <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-sm-3 item">
      <div class="box"><img src="{{ favorite.aircraft.image.url }}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="{{ favorite.aircraft.title }}"/></a>
          <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ favorite.get_absolute_url }}">{{ favorite.aircraft.name }}</a></h3>
          <h4>Manufacturer: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.manufacturer }}</i></h4>
          <h4>Range: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.maximum_range }} NM</i></h4>
          <h4> Passengers: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.passengers }}</i></h4>
          <h4> Speed: <i>{{ favorite.aircraft.cruising_speed }} KT</i></h4>
          <button class=" favorite btn btn-default {% if aircraft.id in favorited_aircraft_ids %}added{% endif %}" data-aircraft-id="{{ aircraft.id }}"><span class="add">Add</span><span class="remove">Remove</span> Favorite</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {%endfor%}
{% else %}
  <h2 class="text-center">Opps.. You don't seem to have any favourited posts..</h2></div>
{% endif %}
```

---

this answer took a lot longer to write than expected :/

Comment: Nice answer, however what about the different field names for the airline model? How/where would they be inserted?

Comment: since you said you "styled them the same" i assumed that template worked for both models... if the models are different, you really need to treat them as such, and just make two templates and use two loops.

Comment: in case one of the two just has more attributes, you could add them in little if blocks inside this solution. {% if favorite.attribute %} stuff here {% endif %}

Comment: How would I implement the two loops? That seems crazily difficult lool

Comment: see Resley's answer ;) (you'll still need to fix the favorite thing though)